# Docker build doesn't pick TARGETARCH arg value when running on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: linux, docker, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

I’m running `docker build` on an Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance, and using `TARGETARCH` arg to identify the target architecture:

```
FROM python:3.12.1-slim-bookworm AS build

ARG TARGETARCH
RUN echo "arch is ${TARGETARCH}"
```

For some reason, docker build doesn’t pick the `TARGETARCH` value, see below:

```
Step 1/46 : FROM python:3.12.1-slim-bookworm AS build
 ---> 16c231298165
Step 2/46 : ARG TARGETARCH
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c34eb6f2eaf4
Step 3/46 : RUN echo "arch is ${TARGETARCH}"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5af08adff044
```

When running docker build on an Ubuntu 20.04 EC2 instance, it’s working:

```
#4 [build  1/16] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.12.1-slim-bookworm@sha256:a64ac5be6928c6a94f00b16e09cdf3ba3edd44452d10ffa4516a58004873573e
#4 CACHED

#5 [internal] load build context
#5 transferring context: 65B done
#5 DONE 0.0s

#6 [build  2/16] RUN echo "arch is amd64"
#6 0.193 arch is amd64
#6 DONE 0.2s
```

Same is working on an Amazon Linux 2023 EC2 instance.
Any idea why docker build doesn’t pick up the `TARGETARCH` value when running on Amazon Linux 2?

Comment: The first output is from the "old" Docker builder and not the newer Buildkit system.  In the first case case you're not seeing output because the build step is cached, so Docker is skipping over the `RUN` command.

Comment: @David Maze, thanks. Indeed the problem was related to absence of BuildKit.
The AL2 EC2 instance had Docker version 20.10.25, where BuildKit is still disabled by default.
I enabled BuiltKit and it solved the issue